# Where are the configuration files kept for Project Groups in Netbeans 7?

Tags: windows, netbeans-7

I want to delete some project groups in Netbeans 7.2 that I no longer use.

Netbeans 7.2 & 7.3 don't keep the configuration information for Project Groups in $USER_HOME/.netbeans as previous versions did.  The closest I've been able to find is this [blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/where_are_project_group_settings) that describes where project group properties files are kept in Netbeans 6.x, 7.0, & 7.1.

Answer (score 5):

Netbeans 7.3 stores the groups in the same location as 7.2, but you must create the first group before seeing the folders. The folder is  %USER_HOME%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups

Comment: Netbeans 7.4 also puts under similar path and it is `%USER_HOME%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups`

Comment: netbeans 8.1 puts them %USER_HOME%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you ever use Linux Netbeans 8.0.2:
~/.netbeans/8.0.2/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui/groups/

Answer (score 1):

The path to the Project Groups properties files can be found in 
%USER_HOME%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\projectui\groups.  A list of properties files with names corresponding to the project groups in Netbeans will be here.  To remove a project group, delete it's associated properties file.  Restart Netbeans and the offending project groups should disappear.

Version 7.3 keeps the properties files somewhere else.